# Retrieving pose of an object from an image or bag file

Tags: ros, pose, object-recognition, grasping, object-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Does anyone know a working package for retrieving pose (3D position) of an object from an image or bag file? I used Objects of Daily Use Finder (ODUfinder) and tod_training + tod_detecting pair. They work quite good but I can't retrieve the pose of the objects in the images or the input from a camera.

The two packages can recognize the objects existing in database, tod_detect also gives an estimation of the POSE but JUST VISUALLY. So somehow it computes the pose as it can give it visually but I don't know how I can get it numerically.

Thank you for your help,

Best regards..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9230/retrieving-pose-of-an-object-from-an-image-or-bag-file/) by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running the recognizer node from tod_detecting and are seeing text output like

"Object name = " << object.objectName << ", imageId = " << object.imgIdx

then that is generated from line 167 of recognizer.cpp.

Each of the ObjectInfo objects referenced there have rvec and tvec members (see this) which presumably store the pose of the object. You could modify that loop to print out or otherwise output the pose as well as the name.

---

Originally posted by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) with karma: 236 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the "posest" package will help you. I have not used it yet but seem like it does what you want

---

Originally posted by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) with karma: 370 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-11**:
thanks for the reply I will search it by the way I found the answer maybe I should post it.